# Move CAEmitterCell animation in Specific Direction

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

I need move the `CAEmitterCell` Particles in a "U" direction. The particle starts a X position  moves all the way down till "Y" and returns back to X + delta postion creating an path shaped "U".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with `CAEmitterCell` was able to achieve curve animation by the particle.

`CAEmitterCell` properties will achieve this . Using `velocity` , `xAcceleration` and `yAcceleration` should solve the problem :)